# Factor Analysis in scikit learn: Many zero loadings

Tags: factor-analysis, scikit-learn

I am trying to apply Factor Analysis to a dataset with about 200 datapoints and 8 variables. 
When setting the n_components parameter to 8, I get a loading matrix with loadings
for three factors that are nonzero, the rest is exactly zero.
Choosing n_components less than 8, all loadings become nonzero.
Should I be worried about this behavior? It seems to me that exactly zero loadings
should not happen.

Comment: Two questions: 1) Is `n_components` stands for the number of components/factors you extract? 2) Are you performing principal component analysis or factor analysis (in narrow sense)? - for PCA and FA are not quite the same thing.

Comment: n_components is indeed the number of factors that I want to extract. I am performing Factor analysis, not PCA using http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.FactorAnalysis.html

Comment: I think this link explains it: http://www.dummies.com/programming/big-data/data-science/data-science-using-python-to-perform-factor-and-principal-component-analysis/

Comment: Here is a Link from a new user (I do not know how to convert it into a comment) http://www.dummies.com/programming/big-data/data-science/data-science-using-python-to-perform-factor-and-principal-component-analysis/